# How to put file in yum repository?

Tags: linux, wget, vmware, fedora, yum

I am new to Linux environment. I have an vmware esxi server, I have created a virtual machine with Fedora 17. I want to install dropbox rpm file, but can't find the a way to transfer the file to `yum` repository.

I tried downloading the file using `wget` but the transfer rate is very slow. here is the code i used to download the file:

```
wget "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

so i decided to download the dropbox file and put it in the `yum` repository, and install it directly.

how to transfer the file to `yum` repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The repositories are centrally managed, and putting packages there is not permitted for most users.

However, after downloading the rpm file using yum to download from a repository is unnecessary.

Simply run the command `sudo rpm -U <path-to-rpm-file>` to install the package.

For details on the rpm command see: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch02s03.html

Comment: i understand but the package is in the host machine, i can't access it in the guest machine. how can i access the file in host?

Comment: Then you have several options: 
    
1: Use a shared folder between the host and guest
    
2: If the guest has ssh you can use `scp` ( http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php )
    
3: There is also a vmware command for transfering files: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Copy-VMGuestFile.html
    
4: The really hard way: Setting up your own yum repository. See: [https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum_Repository.html]